# Dynamically build ListView with JSON Array

Tags: android, json, adapter

I have a PHP script that returns a JSON array.  Each JSON object in the array is a person, and has relevant information such as name, phone number, age.

What I want to do is dynamically build a ListView that will display the information, where each element of the list displays a name, a phone number, and an age.

Right now I have basic code that loops through my JSON array, but how do I set up my Adapter so that it displays these 3 separate pieces of information? I know how to display a single item such as a name, but I'm not 100% sure on how to create an adapter that can display multiple items from a JSON object.

```
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_doctor_list);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
                (getApplicationContext(), R.layout.doctor_item, listItems);
            JSONObject doctor;

            for(int i =0; i < json.length(); i++){
                doctor = json.getJSONObject(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
JSONArray content;

public MyAdapter(Context context, JSONArray content) {
    this.context = context;
    this.content = content;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return content.length();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return content.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = content.get(position);
    viewHolder.name.setText(jsonObject.optString("name"));

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView name, location, whatever;
}

}
```

and `my_layout.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView id="name" />
    <TextView id="location" />
    <TextView id="whatever" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So getView() essentially adds the text for me. I call this function on every JSONObject and then call setAdapter()?

Comment: No, you create your adapter by passing the context and the json array, then you call `setAdapter()`. Or do both at once: `setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, jsonarray))`. `getView()` will be called for you whenever needed by the `ListView`.